# How to Obtain a Google Documents List Data API client ID and a client secret

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

How do I do this?

1. When you create your application, you register it with Google. Google then provides information you'll need later, such as a client ID and a client secret.
2. Activate the Google Documents List Data API in the Services pane of the Google APIs Console. (If it isn't listed in the Console, then skip this step.)
3. When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular scope of access.

Answer (score 1):

Note : it is just for information

See How To Make Client ID and Client Secret with Images
See this link http://aahow.com/how-to-make-client-id-and-client-secret-for-login-with-google-list-9

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to enable the Documents List API in the APIs Console, but you have to generate your OAuth 2.0 credentials in the API Access tab of the same console: https://code.google.com/apis/console